# Parsing file name for Dynamic Choice Parameter in Jenkins with a Groovy script

Tags: linux, parsing, groovy, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to generate a drop-down for a Jenkins job that will parse out the version numbers from the file names in a Linux directory. I have gotten it to work most of the way but I think my lack of knowledge of groovy has me at a standstill. Here is the code I have:

```
Arrays.asList(new File("/path/to/files").list().join(", ").findAll(/(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)/))
```

and my file names look like:

- returns?-?1.0.0.19?.war
- returns?-?1.0.0.20?.war

What I get as a return from the Jenkins script console is:

> Result: [[1.0.0.19, 1.0.0.20]]

This is essentially what I want but in the Jenkins job I get one item in the drop-down that is everything inside the outer brackets.

> [1.0.0.19, 1.0.0.20]

I think the second set of brackets is the issue and I have tried to remove them using Groovy's .minus() method, double escaping the brackets, with no luck. I have also tried the .split() method, with no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need `Arrays.asList()`. Below should suffice.

```
new File("/opt/staples/ci-tools/workspace/archive/returns")
              .list()
              .join(',')
              .findAll(/(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)/)
```

Comment: That worked wonderfully! Thank you! I added a .sort() to the end too, to make it easier to look through.